# Creating Chart in Excel using Jfreechart and poi in java

Tags: java, jfreechart

This is the error I'm getting..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.DrawingManager2.getDrawingGroup(DrawingManager2.java:125)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.DrawingManager2.allocateShapeId(DrawingManager2.java:71)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.EscherAggregate.convertPatriarch(EscherAggregate.java:988)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.EscherAggregate.convertUserModelToRecords(EscherAggregate.java:821)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.EscherAggregate.getRecordSize(EscherAggregate.java:508)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalSheet.preSerialize(InternalSheet.java:1567)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getBytes(HSSFWorkbook.java:1285)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.write(HSSFWorkbook.java:1205)
        at NewTest.main(NewTest.java:94)
```

And here is the code..

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPatriarch;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPicture;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;
public class NewTest {  
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

                /* Read Excel and the Chart Data */
                FileInputStream chart_file_input = new FileInputStream("/home/prasanna/jfree.xls");
                /* Read data into HSSFWorkbook */
                HSSFWorkbook my_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(chart_file_input);
                /* This worksheet contains the Pie Chart Data */
                HSSFSheet my_sheet = my_workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                /* Create JFreeChart object that will hold the Pie Chart Data */
                DefaultPieDataset my_pie_chart_data = new DefaultPieDataset();
                /* We now iterate over the Excel Workbook data and Populate Pie Chart Data */
                /* Create an Iterator object */
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = my_sheet.iterator(); 
                /* Loop through worksheet data and populate Pie Chart Dataset */
                String chart_label="a";
                Number chart_data=0;            
                while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                        //Read Rows from Excel document
                        Row row = rowIterator.next();  
                        //Read cells in Rows and get chart data
                        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                                while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next(); 
                                        switch(cell.getCellType()) { 
                                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                                chart_data=cell.getNumericCellValue();
                                                break;
                                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                                chart_label=cell.getStringCellValue();
                                                break;
                                        }
                                }
                /* Add data to the data set */          
                my_pie_chart_data.setValue(chart_label,chart_data);
                }               
                /* Create a logical chart object with the chart data collected */
                JFreeChart myPieChart=ChartFactory.createPieChart("Excel Pie Chart Java Example",my_pie_chart_data,true,true,false);
                /* Specify the height and width of the Pie Chart */
                int width=640; /* Width of the chart */
                int height=480; /* Height of the chart */
                float quality=1; /* Quality factor */
                /* We don't want to create an intermediate file. So, we create a byte array output stream 
                and byte array input stream
                And we pass the chart data directly to input stream through this */             
                /* Write chart as JPG to Output Stream */
                ByteArrayOutputStream chart_out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();          
                ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(chart_out,quality,myPieChart,width,height);
                /* We now read from the output stream and frame the input chart data */
                InputStream feed_chart_to_excel=new ByteArrayInputStream(chart_out.toByteArray());
                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(feed_chart_to_excel);
                /* Add picture to workbook */
                int my_picture_id = my_workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
                /* We can close Piped Input Stream. We don't need this */
                feed_chart_to_excel.close();
                /* Close PipedOutputStream also */
                chart_out.close();
                /* Create the drawing container */
                HSSFPatriarch drawing = my_sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
                /* Create an anchor point */
                ClientAnchor my_anchor = new HSSFClientAnchor();
                /* Define top left corner, and we can resize picture suitable from there */
                my_anchor.setCol1(4);
                my_anchor.setRow1(5);
                /* Invoke createPicture and pass the anchor point and ID */
                HSSFPicture  my_picture = drawing.createPicture(my_anchor, my_picture_id);
                /* Call resize method, which resizes the image */
                my_picture.resize();
                /* Close the FileInputStream */
                String file = "/home/prasanna/picture.xls";
                   //if(wb instanceof XSSFWorkbook) file += "x";
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                my_workbook.write(out);
                out.close();            
        }
}
```

Comment: can you also provide the input file so it is possible to reproduce the error?

Comment: Its a case of IndexOutOfBoundsException. Can you please recheck the array size that you are trying to access? May be initialization is wrong or something.